# Rails & Webpack: How do I call functions in application pack?

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I can't seem to figure out how to call a function in Rails 6 with Webpacker. If calling them in the console I get the message that the function is not defined.
How can I call these function? Or is there a good reason why I should not do this?

The problem in it's simplest form:
In application.js I have a function called something.

```
# app/javascripts/packs/application.js
function something() {
    console.log("something")
}
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", something())

# console
something
```

But when I use this in a link with onClick(), or in a *.js.erb file, or just put the function in the console, I get the error `ReferenceError: something is not defined`

The function does show up in my application.js file that Webpacker compiles

I have my webpack set up as follows: (I have only adapted the webpack config to include jQuery and popper.js)

```
# config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',  
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
    ActionCable: 'actioncable',
  })
)

const config = environment.toWebpackConfig()

config.resolve.alias = {
  jquery: "jquery/src/jquery",
}


module.exports = environment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that webpack doesn't expose these functions.
To be able to call them from a `*.js.erb` file, you need to define them on the window.

```
# app/javascripts/packs/application.js
function something() {
    console.log("something")
}
window.app.something
```

in your `*.js.erb`

```
window.app.something();
```